# Change bibliography style according to bst file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

I am writing document as MastersDoctoralThesis class
In this file I define

```
\documentclass[12pt, english]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, bibstyle=numeric, citestyle=bwl-FU, sorting=nyt, natbib=true]{biblatex} %chem-acs  bwl-FU  authoryear
\addbibresource{biblio_lib.bib}

TEXT

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}]
```

As result I get References formed like for example:
[image]

The challenge is to form references like it is made in Astronomy and Astrophysics Journal (or similar, close to).

[image]

There is a aa.bst file available at A&A journal www page. How can I use it with my MastersDoctoralThesis.cls or right in my tex file to get some close to desired result ???
Dont even know where to start with this problem.

---

[link to aa.bst](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/bibtex/aa.bst)

[link to MastersDoctoralThesis](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)
[direct link to MastersDoctoralThesis.cls](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwuvb9cYGf0SOE9kcnhtZm45WjQ)

Comment: If you want to (or have to) use a specific `bst` file, you *mustn't* use `biblatex`.  (`biblatex` doesn't read `bst` files...)  Instead, you must you BibTeX directly. You may also want to use a suitable citation management package, e.g., `natbib`.

Comment: Incidentally, is the document class file `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` available online somewhere?

Comment: Add link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwuvb9cYGf0SOE9kcnhtZm45WjQ

Comment: Ok, so bst file is not a option. How to change refstyle at all? in class file?

Comment: Why isnt usung the bst file an option?

Comment: I am not sure. But when I try to change in to natbib latex give me an errors in class file. So I dont know how to deal with natbib and this class file.

Comment: After unloading `biblatex` and loading `natbib` (and providing a `\bibliographystyle` directive), did you delete all aux files before recompiling?

Comment: I delete only *.blb file. Ok, I will try to do it tomorrow. Maybe you can write me some example ?

Comment: Surely you don't want to delete the `.bib` file! You should delete the `.aux` file and any `.bbl` file. If you want somebody to provide an example, why don't you provide a minimal example with your current setup so that somebody only needs to adapt it?

Comment: @cfr - I hope the OP deleted the `blg` files? (`blb` looks like a typo...)

Comment: @Mico Let's hope so ... ;).

Comment: If you answer the question yourself, please do not add the answer as an edit to your question, but post an answer yourself. On this site we separate answers and questions, this allows future visitors to benefit from your answer and find it more quickly.

Comment: @Mico If the OP wouldn't have removed the header, it would have been clear immediately where to get this class/template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main error reason was not deleted *.aux file 
I delete all bibtex and rewrite refs in natbib with aa.bst style

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % add references to table of context
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref} %% to avoid \citeads line fills
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,} %% natbib format for A&A and ApJ

\bibliographystyle{aa} % style aa.bst
\bibliography{biblio_lib.bib} % your references Yourfile.bib
```

I also have to update commands to corect read ADS bibtex citations.

```
\newcommand{\apjs}{ApJS}
\newcommand{\apj}{ApJ}
\newcommand{\apjl}{ApJ}
\newcommand{\mnras}{MNRAS}
\newcommand{\aap}{A\&A}
\newcommand{\aj}{AJ}
\newcommand{\nat}{Nature}
\newcommand{\bain}{Bull.~Astron.~Inst.~Netherlands} 
\newcommand{\araa}{ARA\&A}
\newcommand{\icarus}{Icarus}
```

As result now I have
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this bst file (https://github.com/yangcht/AA-bibstyle-with-hyperlink). I modified it so that the clickable adsurl link and doi links will be shown up in the reference list.

What you need to do is just to replace the "aa.bst" file with this "aa_url.bst".

Below is an example, magenta is the doi links to the journal while the blue links are to the ADS.

[image]

**Note that do please use the bib entry generated by the ADS website.**

Comment: Instead of just posting a link could you provide an MWE with an image of the result?

Comment: Hi, thx for suggestions. I added an image.

Comment: were is a few errors:
function on line 1120 should look like 

`FUNCTION {make.href.hyperref}
{
  "\href {" swap$ * "} {" * swap$ * "}" * 
}`

without extra `}` in the end. 
Also there is error on line 1111
`nameptr is already a type "integer-global-variable" function name
---line 1111 of file aa_url.bst
 : integers { nameptr
 :                    namesleft numnames }`

Comment: Yes, you are right, I corrected that. Thanks for pointing it out. But I can not reproduce the error you mentioned at line 1111. And this line `integers { nameptr : namesleft numnames }` is originally in the official `aa.bst` file. You should consider if you are lack of any A&A environments, like aa.cls